# "Go to file" with VSCode, instead of goToSymbol

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see this line in keybindings.json

```
{ "key": "shift+cmd+o",   "command": "workbench.action.gotoSymbol" },
```

which you can see here:

[image]

However, I am trying to find the shortcut for "goToFile" - is there such a shortcut?

Currently, to find a file by name, I use `"goToSymbol"` and then I delete the ampersand and then type the filename and it works, but that's an extra step I'd like to avoid. See:

[image]

So my question is, *does anyone know how to go directly to searching for a file by name, instead of using* `goToSymbol`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ctrl+p by default, `workbench.action.quickOpen`.